# Python background sound, how to know when it stops

Tags: python, winsound

I'm using the `winsound` library to play a file asynchronously. However, I would like to know when the sound is done playing. If the sound is done, then I keep the `flag` set to 1. Otherwise, I set `flag` to 0.

This is my current code:

```
import winsound

winsound.PlaySound('c:\\audiocheck.net_whitenoise.wav',winsound.SND_ALIAS | winsound.SND_ASYNC)
flag = 1
print(flag)
```

Comment: Are you opposed to blocking until the sound is done playing?

Comment: Or can you explain why you need to know when the sound stops playing?

Comment: I need the sound to be blaying on the background because I'm using it to create a reaction in an EEG spectrum that's why I also need the flags because I need to know exactly when the sound began playing and when it stopped

Comment: I see. Can you get the duration of the sound in the given `.wav` file?

Comment: Yes, 10 seconds

Comment: Okay, can you just start the sound and then sleep for 10 seconds?

Comment: No because at the same time I'm reading values and sending them to a CSV file, in other words I need the sound to be playing  in the background and to keep doing what I mentioned and also know the flag state (0- no sound, 1-sound playing) which I'm also sending to the CSV file

Comment: That did play the sound but I'm still getting this AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'join'

Answer (score -1):

```
import winsound
import time

start = time.time()
winsound.PlaySound('c:\\audiocheck.net_whitenoise.wav',winsound.SND_ALIAS | winsound.SND_ASYNC)
flag = 1
while flag == 1:
    elapsed = time.time() - start
    if elapsed >= 10:
        flag = 0
```